Problema con el config.xml al usar cordova (Creacion de apps moviles)
es la primera vez que hago una pregunta aquí. Creo que el problema es muy fácil pero no lo encuentro.
Actualmente me encuentro haciendo una aplicación móvil con quasar y cordova, el cual se encarga de cargar una lista escanear códigos y si esta marcarlo en color verde. Estoy trabajando en una opción para exportar esa lista por medio de una opción de compartir clásica de todas las apps, al momento de agregar el pluggin de "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" he tenido problemas con el documento config.xml (src-cordova/config.xml) y no puedo avanzar por culpa de ese error. Les agradecería si me pueden ayudar.
El codigo de mi config.xml es el siguiente:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.cordova.quasar.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Lista Cero</name>
    <description>Proyecto creado para facilitar el proceso de busqueda de productos y reducir errores humanos.</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="about:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="cdvfile:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        </config-file>
        <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.9:9400" />
    </platform>
    <feature name="BackbuttonPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.badrit.Backbutton.BackbuttonPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>

Y el problema que se genera es este:

Configure project :app
WARNING: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.


Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile resource file: C:\Lista-Cero\src-cordova\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:
. Cause: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[34,85]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?uses-permission&android:name&android). Check logs for more details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 1s
33 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 29 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: \Inventario - copia\Lista-Cero\src-cordova\platforms\android\tools\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug
App • Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1
App • Updated Cordova config.xml
App • ⚠️   FAIL  Cordova CLI has failed
Igual les comparto el config.xml que se genera en el directorio que se muestra en el error el cual es este, C:\Lista-Cero\src-cordova\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.cordova.quasar.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="BackbuttonPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.badrit.Backbutton.BackbuttonPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
    </feature>
    <name>Lista Cero</name>
    <description>Proyecto creado para facilitar el proceso de busqueda de productos y reducir errores humanos.</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="http://192.168.1.9:9400" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="about:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="cdvfile:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </config-file>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.9:9400" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.
